# Stepper Driver signal noise problem (Ground Loop)

Tags: noise, ground-loop, emf

I have an BluePill board (Arm Cortex M3 Dev. Board). Also a a4988 stepper motor driver. BluePill is powered from usb of my PC. Stepper motor driver is powered by external power supply which is 220V -> 12V. Both my pc and the external power supply are connected to same plugs. The grounds are wired between a4988 and BluePill. The weird problem is, when I connect my PC13 pin to STEP pin. I can smoothly drive my stepper motor. When I connect to another pin such as A7, A6 my stepper motor turns randomly. Power supply and wires are too close to each other (approximately 10-15cm). I think that emf occurs on the wire and the noise causes to move motor randomly but why it doesn't happen when I connect it to PC13.

When I connect a wire to STEP pin and the other side of wire is unconnected, there is also random turns.

Added my setup as @laptop2d said.
[Here is my setup](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZS-upsComkEzA_OiCKGNXqmRky8yidF4)

Comment: Provide a diagram of your setup, we are not at your bench and its too hard to troubleshoot problems via telekinesis

Comment: @Ames: Please embed your image into your post. This has several benefits: all the information will be in one place; we can read the text and see the schematic at the same time; more people will respond since they don't have to follow links; the question will still be intelligible when the link dies.

Comment: I could not because when i pressed img button, stackexchange adds with invalidated img url, so I added to my google drive and linked to post

Comment: guys any help ?

Answer (score 0):

On the BluePill board, PC13 sinks LED1 through a resistor. So it's 3v3 -> LED -> resistor-> PC13 -> step pin.
Try enabling pull-up on the other pin you want to use eg A7.